# Proof with multiple cases theorem

Tags: coq, proof

I have a hypothesis of the form

```
H := check_smaller_thm 1 2 : {2 <= 1} + {2 > 1}
```

I also have a sub goal

```
If check_smaller_thm 1 2 then some stuff else some other stuff
```

I am stuck at this point because I do not see what tactic to use in order to modify H such that I  keep the correct Hypothesis (here, {2 > 1}). Then I would like to use it in my sub goal to keep the correct part of the if.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

EDIT

It seems that

```
If check_smaller_thm 1 2 then some stuff else some other stuff
```

always applies some stuff instead of other stuff. Is that possible ?

Comment: (assuming your keyword `If` is actually lowercase `if`) To answer your edit: in this expression, the `if` reduces indeed, but what you say is not possible. `check_smaller_thm` is a decision procedure and here it is applied to concrete values, so it reduces to a proof that we are in the 2nd case (`2 > 1`). Then `if … then A else B` simply pattern-matches on this value, returns `A` if it falls in the first case and `B` if it falls in the 2nd case. So in this case we get `other stuff`. Have you swapped the theorem’s arguments while writing on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need `destruct (check_smaller_thm 1 2) eqn:Hd`- see the reference manual here ([https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacv.destruct-…-eqn:](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/reasoning-inductives.html#coq:tacv.destruct-%E2%80%A6-eqn:)).

Answer (score 1):

If your theorem `check_smaller_thm 1 2` has type `{2 <= 1} + {2 > 1}`, when
you type the tactic `destruct (check_smaller_thm 1 2)`, it creates two goals.

One of these goals contains the hypothesis `2 <= 1`.  This goal says, *if 2 was smaller than or equal to 1, then the result would be `some_stuff`*.

So it does look like the `if` expression returns `some_stuff`, but it is under a false hypothesis.  You can get rid of this goal by showing that this hypothesis is inconsistent.

Here is an example.  Notice that we spend some time working on the hypothesis named `c2le1`.  Here I use elementary tactics to solve the problem, but `lia` would take care of the problem right away.

```
Require Import Arith Lia.

Lemma tutu (A : Type) (some_stuff : A) (some_other_stuff : A)
  (check_smaller_thm : forall n m, {m <= n}+{m > n}) :
(if check_smaller_thm 1 2 then some_stuff else some_other_stuff)  = some_other_stuff.
Proof.
destruct check_smaller_thm as [c2le1 | c1lt2].
  apply le_S_n in c2le1; inversion c2le1.
reflexivity.
Qed.
```